# CSVファイルのデータからJSON 形式のフォーマットでSFへインポート

Tags: python, csv

やりたいこと：
csvファイルのデータを抽出したデータを１カラム・１行ずつでループさせてSFにインポートしたいです。
下記のコードで試してみましたがエラーが表示されます。
Json形式でデータをインポートしますので、抽出したデータを１カラム・１行ずつでループさせてSFにインポートする方法ありますでしょうか。

CSVのデータ

```
A       B     C         D
アメリカ 1234  テキサス 　 @gmail.com
カナダ　 1234　バンクーバー @gmail.com
```

CSVのデータ（カンマ区切り）

```
A,B,C,D
アメリカ,1234,テキサス,@gmail.com
カナダ,1234,バンクーバー,@gmail.com
```

JSON形式でインポート

```
#sf.Contact.upsert('customExtIdField__c/11999',{'LastName': 'Smith','Email': 'smith@example.com'})
```

コード

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig',header=0)

df_a = df1[["B"]] 
print(df_a) 

df_b = df1[["C"]] 
print(df_b)

df_c = df1[["D"]] 
print(df_c)

SALESFORCE_USERNAME = '123'
PASSWORD = '123'
SECURITY_TOKEN = '123'

# Authentication settings
sf = Salesforce(username=SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
password=PASSWORD,
security_token=SECURITY_TOKEN)

#JSON形式でSFにインポートする方法です。→https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce
#Other Optionsを参考

#sf.Contact.upsert('customExtIdField__c/11999',{'LastName': 'Smith','Email': 'smith@example.com'})

#SFにインポートするコード
# for j in range(len(df_i)):→抽出したデータを１カラム・１行ずつでループさせてSFにインポートしたい！
 sf.Contact.upsert('Test__c/'str(df_a),{'Test2__c':str(df_b),'Email':str(df_c)})
```

エラー内容

```
S C:\Users\test\Documents\salesforce> & C:/Users/test/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/test/Documents/salesforce/check.py
  File "c:\Users\test\Documents\salesforce\check.py", line 36
    sf.Contact.upsert('Test__c/'str(df_a),{'Test2__c':str(df_b),'Email':str(df_c)})

                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーメッセージが`sf.Lead.upsert`で、提示されているソースが`sf.Contact.upsert`で違うものが実行されているか質問時に間違えて違うものを提示されたのでしょうか？ それから依然としてCSVデータが`カンマ区切り`の生のファイルデータで提示されていません。 またCSVと対になる望ましいJSONデータの形式を提示しておいた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。`sf.Contact.upsert`また`カンマ区切り`で指定しました。JSONデータも記載しました。

Comment: 提示された生CSVデータの`カナダ`の行が変(数字の1が全角の`１`なのと数字と`バンクーバー`の間が`カンマ`ではなく`ピリオド`)ですが、合っていますか？ それからエラー該当行で`str(df_a)`とか`str(df_b)`とか指定すると、`df_a`や`df_b`はDataFrameなので、そのDataFrame全体が指定されたのと同じになり、DataFrameとしての列名/インデックス番号や全ての行のデータも含まれますが、それは理解していますか？ `SalesForce`モジュールやそのメソッドが如何とかよりも、先ず出来た文字列をいったん何かの変数に入れるなりして、`print()`で変換結果を確認した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: タイトルの "SF にインポート" だと何のことだか分かりづらいので、"JSON 形式にフォーマット" とかの方がよさそうです。

Comment: @cubick
ご指摘ありがとうございます。分かりやすく変更しておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前回の [PythonでCSVファイルのデータを抽出、全ての列空白を除外](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74034/) で回答した様に、`pandas.DataFrame.agg` を使う方法もあります。

```py
import pandas as pd

Result = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
           usecols=['B', 'C', 'D'], dtype=str, encoding='utf_8_sig')\
         .agg(lambda x: ('Test__c/'+x[0], {'Test2__c':x[1], 'Email':x[2]}), axis=1)

for r in Result:
  print(*r)
=>
Test__c/1234 {'Test2__c': 'テキサス', 'Email': '@gmail.com'}
Test__c/1234 {'Test2__c': 'バンクーバー', 'Email': '@gmail.com'}
```

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ただ上記のように指定しても下記のようにエラーが表示されます。`TypeError: upsert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`
Json形式なので出来ないでしょうか。

Comment: おそらくですが、`sf.Contact.upsert(*r)` とするとよろしいかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-↲

from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce import format_soql, format_external_id

import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',encoding='utf_8_sig')

#一行ずつ
for index, item in df1.iterrows():
    # print(item['A'], item['B'], item['C'], item['D'])
    external_id = format_external_id('Test_c', item['A'])
    i = external_id, {'Test2__c': item['C'],'Email': item['D']}
    #出力して確認
    print(i)
```

Comment: @こちらも回答ありがとうございます。こちらも上記と同様に`TypeError: upsert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`が表示されます。まだ詳しくわからないですがdata形式違うのでしょうか。

Comment: 修正しました。＋検証できる環境がないので、ここまでです。

Comment: カスタムIDにいろんな文字を含められる、ということみたいですが、format_external_idを使うようです。